# url rewrite not working on my wamp please help me for this

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My localhost link `/work_Seo/blog-single.php?pid=6`

and I want to change it into `/work_Seo/blog/pid/6`

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^work_Seo/blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /work_Seo/blog-single.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

all htaccess configuration is done but still its not working

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make sure that all of your links look like `/work_Seo/blog/pid/6`. **You have to generate your links to look that way**, the rule that you've used wont magically change the links in your content. Second, you said you want your links to look like `/work_Seo/blog/pid/6`, but your rule doesn't match the `pid`. Either change your links so that they don't have the *pid* in the URL, or add it in the rule's pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^work_Seo/blog/pid/([0-9]+)/?$ /work_Seo/blog-single.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```